# How to check if a download is running ? DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I would like to check if a download is currently running. I am using the code bellow:

```
public static boolean isDownloading(Context context){

    DownloadManager.Query query = null;
    Cursor c = null;
    DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    if(query!=null) {

        //return true;
        query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL|
                DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
    } else {
        Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOW" , "NO ");
        return false;
    }
    c = downloadManager.query(query);
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        switch(status) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD","PAUSED");
               break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD","PENDING");
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD","RUNNING");
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD","SUCCESSFUL");
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD","FAILED");
                break;
        }
    }
    Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD","DEFAULT");
    c.close();
    return true;
}
```

I have the following logcat even though a download is running : `09-04 09:39:42.381 30213-31215/com.bytel.velizy.automation I/AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD: DEFAULT`

I have tried to reduce the previous code into this but it did not work.

```
DownloadManager.Query query = null;
Cursor c = null;
DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
query = new DownloadManager.Query();
if(query!=null) {
    return true;
     } else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `Cursor c = downloadManager .query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(referenceId));

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {`

Comment: I don't know how to get the id of the download, so I have used flag.
How did you catch referenceId please?

Comment: when you add request in download manager like this `referenceId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);` This is for the case that you add download request yourself.

Comment: I understand now... I have open a webpage which starts a download. I will modify my code in order to get the id.

Comment: you don't have to open a webpage to start a download. You can add it in your code programmatically like `String appURI = downloadString; Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(appURI);
                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri); request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(myFile));
 downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);`

Comment: Thanks @MehranZamani :)

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to get Status of a specific download In that case when you start your download at that time downloadManager.enqueue() method returns downloadId which is unique for each download so you can save this and use to get DownloadStatus like this

Here start download return you downloadId

```
 public long startDownload(String downloadurl) {
                DownloadManager downloadManager =
                        (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                try {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadurl));
// enqueue method retuns downloadId
                    return  downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("DOWNLOADED_INFO", "startDownload =" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

This downloadId passed to getStatus method

```
public static int getStatus(Context context , long downloadId) {
    DownloadManager downloadManager =
            (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    query.setFilterById(downloadId);// filter your download bu download Id
    Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        c.close();
        Log.i("DOWNLOAD_STATUS", String.valueOf(status));
        return status;
    }
    Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD", "DEFAULT");
    return -1;
}
```

To check If current file is downloadng

```
public static boolean isDownloading(Context context , long downloadId){
        return getStatus(context , downloadId) == com.mozillaonline.providers.DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING;
    }
```

Above method is for checking the status of a particular download.
If you want to check the status of your download manager that any file is downloading or in paused status you can check by this method

```
public static boolean checkStatus(Context context , int status) {
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();

        query.setFilterByStatus(status);
        Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            c.close();
            Log.i("DOWNLOAD_STATUS", String.valueOf(status));
            return true;
        }
        Log.i("AUTOMATION_DOWNLOAD", "DEFAULT");
        return false;
    }
```

and then simply call this method

```
checkStatus(context , DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
```

Comment: I'm thankful for the time you have spent on my post. Now my code works very well. The function startDownload() and checkStatus() were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use STATUS_RUNNING To Access Status of download manager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#STATUS_RUNNING